# What exactly does the Remainder Estimate for Integral Test actually mean? $R_n \le \int_{n}^{\infty}f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\int_{n+1}^{\infty}f(x)dx \le R_n \le \int_{n}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$

What does this actually mean?

Let's use n=5.

The $R_5$ is the error of the partial sum $S_5$

That error is less than the sum of the remaining terms from 5 to $\infty$ ?

Why is that?

Also, why is it greater than sum of the remaining terms from 6 to $\infty$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by noting that you can approximate the value of an serie by a finite sum
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \approx \sum_{n=0}^{k} a_n$$
say, for example, $k=5$ (as in OP), so
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \approx \sum_{n=0}^{5} a_n$$
but the real sum is
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n = \sum_{n=0}^{5} a_n +\sum_{n=6}^{\infty} a_n $$
and this difference between your approximation and the real sum is the remainder:
$$R_5=\sum_{n=6}^{\infty} a_n.$$

The inequality
$$\int_{n+1}^{\infty}f(x)dx \le R_n \le \int_{n}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$
gives you a maximum and a minimum value for that remainder (the error in using the finite sum as an approximation) when you analyses a serie by the [Integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).

Let's look an example: The series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+...$$
converges by the integral test as
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^x} dx= \frac{1}{\ln2}<\infty$$
we can seek for an approximation of the sum by summing the first three terms:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \approx \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8} = \frac{7}{8}$$
and we can ask "how good" this approximation is. Using the remainder estimate we have
$$\int_{4}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^x} dx \le R_3 \le \int_{3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^x} dx$$
so
$$\frac{1}{16\ln2} \le R_3 \le \frac{1}{8\ln2}$$
or
$$0.090168 \le R_3 \le 0.18034$$

In fact this is an [Geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) that we can know the exact value of the sum and of the remainder as
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}=1$$
and
$$R_3=\frac{1}{8}=0.125$$
compare this with the estimate given by the integral.

About the validity of the inequality, take a look on the following
[image]
In (a) there's a comparison between the sum starting from $1$ with the integral and in (b) a comparison between the sum starting from $2$ with the integral. Note that the sum is the total area of the rectangles and the integral is the area below the curve.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to type up your very nice explanation on how to USE the inequality, however, I am wondering where the inequality comes from and/or why it actually is true.    In my example, the R5 remainder equals the 6th term to infinity sum.   So why is R5 less than the integral from 5 to infinity?

Comment: I think it's because of the integral test?   The remainder series is less than the corresponding integral?

Comment: https://youtu.be/fbSG-cX4FMI?t=164

Comment: @JackOfAll I added additional explanation for the inequality. Also consider accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your effort!  Very generous man!

Comment: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/EstimatingSeries.aspx

Comment: Diego, what is your station in life?  Student?  Career?

Comment: @JackOfAll I teach in Brazil's Federal Institute, but I'm also pursuing my Phd. (coincidentally I just complete the "about me" section)